# Facebook AppRequest with object_id gives 500 error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas

I am trying to make game request as it is using the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.4

When I try to send a given object nothing happens and in console I see the 500 error.
`POST https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/apprequests 500 (Internal Server Error)`

This happens only if I use valid object_id. If I put wrong ID or object id from another application I receive Error with explanation. If the object id is valid I receive 500 error.

The parameters I use to make request

```
{
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: message,
    action_type: 'send',
    object_id: 12345678901,
}
```

If I remove action_type and object_id everything works. If I use action_type: 'turn' everything also works.

What can be the reason for such error?

Comment: This issue was probably the same as this bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/862534523829812/. Is this still happening for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the Facebook platform bug. The Facebook Bug reporting is better place for such questions. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/